# React lazy load for a function, not a component

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-functional-component

I am working on a React v16 app and need to load a heavy (IMO) library for xlsx export of data.

I'm using functional components/hooks.

I understand and have used the `<Suspense />` component and `lazy` for lazy loading modules. but since this item is not a component, it is simply a library function i need to run with an onClick event, i can't use lazy/suspense.

How can i lazy load this function only when needed? (writeXlsxFile)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
//...
import writeXlsxFile from "write-excel-file";

//...
  const fileCreate = async () => {
    await writeXlsxFile(exportData, {
      schema,
      fileName: `file.xlsx`,
    });
  };

return(//...
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "this function"? Do you mean fileCreate or writeXlsxFile?

Comment: i just updated it cuz i was thinking the same thing, kinda vague. the writeXlsxFile function is what i want to  lazy load

Comment: but if i import at the top of file, its not lazy loading. i need it to selectively load only when needed, aka, when the user needs to use it

Comment: In any case, `named` imports can be lazy loaded by way of `async`. Ex: `async () => { const writeXlsxFile = await import ('write-excel-file'), // Whatever you want here}`

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64208216/5690068 answer your question? dynamic import will work, you just need to access it by `module.default`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaScript`, and by direct association, `React`, supports [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

So,

```js
const fileCreate = async () => { 
  const {default: writeXlsxFile} = await import ('write-excel-file')
  void await writeXlsxFile(exportData, {
      schema,
      fileName: `file.xlsx`,
  });
}
```

Comment: bummer im getting a "writeXlsxFile" is not a function error, i did update the names to match, you had writeXlsx, which is updated to writeXlsxFile

Comment: @sao you're still getting the error after updating the names?

Comment: yeah its still there

Comment: Updated @sao. It passed my mind that you're using a `default` import instead of a `named` import (even though `default` imports can be imported by name).

Comment: you got it dude. the second rendition works. i'll have to read up on the default setting. thank you!