# CommonJS vs ES Modules for Express Node

Tags: node.js, express

Could anyone explain what is the best approach for node express app: CommonJS or ES Modules as of today? In the official documentation it shows that CommonJS module is used, however there are many discussions that point to usage of ES Modules for backend development. So I'd like to get some opinions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no "best". CJS is the legacy Node-only version that they had to invent because JS didn't have a module system when Node was invented, and ESM is JS's own module system that was added quite a while back now, but well after Node had become popular. So it's really up to you. There's very little reason to still write CJS today, but it's not "worse" than writing ESM, you're just targeting a different crowd. (And your code won't work in more modern JS solutions like Deno or Bun, for example)

Answer (score 7):

Node.js official docs are excellent at explaining the two different types of module systems. [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

There is a very good chapter in *Node.js Design Patterns, Chapter 2: The Module System (2020)* that describes where CommonJS came from. It emerges from the need to provide a module system for JavaScript in browserless environments simply because one did not exist, other than the AMD and UMD initiatives, and to not rely on `urls` and `<script>` tags for resources. It was successful so became popular.

We now have ECMAScript Modules thanks to the ES2015 official proposal and it attempts to align the management of modules in both server-side and browser environments.

The main points to help you decide are:

1. CommonJS uses the `require` function to load modules and is synchronous. As a result, when you assign a module to `module.exports` for example, it too must be synchronous. If you have asynchronous stages in your module then you can export an uninitialized module but using `require` will mean that there is a chance it won't be ready to use in the code that requires it before it's initialized.
2. ES modules use the `import` keyword to load modules. They are static, so they need to be described at the top level of every module and support loading modules asynchronously. ES modules facilitate static analysis of the dependency tree, making dead code elimination (tree shaking) more efficient.
3. ES modules run implicitly in strict mode (can't be disabled). This is a good thing in many opinions as it enforces good coding practices.
4. In CommonJS you can use the helpful `__filename` and `__dirname`. In ES modules you need to do a workaround to get the same functionality like so:

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { dirname } from 'path'
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = dirname(__filename)
```

5. You can dynamically load modules in CommonJS with `require`:

```js
let usefulModule;
if (process.env.DEV === true) {
   usefulModule = require('./utils/devmodule')
} else {
   usefulModule = require('./utils/prodmodule')
}
```

6. And in ESM by using `import` as function:

```js
let lib;
if (process.env.DEV === true) {
   lib  = await import('./utils/devmodule.js');
   
} else {
   lib  = await import('./utils/prodmodule.js');
}
const usefulModule = lib.usefulModule;
```

One thing I have noticed over the years of programming is that languages and libraries evolve. I have observed a growing shift in Node package docs giving more and more of their examples in ESM format. CommonJS is still the [dominant option](https://bun.sh/blog/commonjs-is-not-going-away) on npm but it tells me the ecosystem is slowly shifting away from CommonJS and towards ESM. Maybe they will run in tandem but such is the nature of evolution, one becomes dominant over the others. All of the projects I work on use the ESM approach. Good luck deciding.

Comment: Number 6 I think you can using the dynamic import https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858782/using-the-dynamic-import-function-on-node-js

Comment: Yes, using the `import()` function but not the keyword. Still a useful link. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for such helpful explanation! I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

CommonJS is still more widely used so it can myabe be easier to work with since many modules can be written for CommonJS. I'd still suggest ESM for a new project, it's cleaner and surprisingly or no, more optimised. There's also a minor performance related thing, ESM imports are asynchronous whereas CommonJS imports are synchronous. Also it has robust type checking and is statically analysable which are not available with CommonJS.